# SOQL Query for all Fields on Object and filter based on certain types

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

I am looking to make dynamic queries, but I want to avoid compound fields in the query. Is there any way to check if the fields is a compound or overall not updateable?

```
    public List<Sobject> DynamicSOQL(String objectName, Set<Object> IdsToQuery) 
    {

        String SobjectApiName = objectName;
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get(SobjectApiName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();

        List<String>apiNames =  new list<String>();

        for(String apiName : fieldMap.keyset())
        {
            apiNames.add(apiName);
        }

        string allstring = string.join(apiNames,',');

        query = 'SELECT ' + allstring + ' FROM ' + SobjectApiName + ' WHERE Id in' :IdsToQuery + ' Limit 3';

        Account[] accList = Database.query(query);

        return accList;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there

You can utilise the [DescribeFieldResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm) object to determine if the running user is able to update the field based on the running users FLS.

Compound fields such as BillingAddress on the account object will return false, the fields which make it up will return true.

Hope this helps

```
public List<Sobject> DynamicSOQL(String objectName, Set<Object> IdsToQuery) 
    {

        String SobjectApiName = objectName;
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get(SobjectApiName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();

        List<String>apiNames =  new list<String>();

        for(String apiName : fieldMap.keyset())
        {
           if(fieldMap.get(apiName).getDescribe().isUpdateable()) {
              apiNames.add(apiName);
           }
        }
```

Comment: what about things like compound fields? or does isUpdateable capture this?

Comment: I updated the answer to give a little more clarity